# Simple task with javascript - Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

Here's a simple form that contains a text field, a dropdown field, and a Submit button, like this:
I created a js file named `script.js` :

```
<form action=" ">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  Category <select name="category">
    <option value="volvo">First</option>
    <option value="saab">Second</option>
    <option value="fiat">Third</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On my index.html I have this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 <p><a href="javascript:(function(){my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');my_script.type='text/javascript';my_script.src='script.js?x=';"> Bookmarklet</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on this article [how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/) I can do that because there's **InstaCalc Bookmarklet** example.
There it says this "Open/overlay a new page. Open a new page or draw a window on the current one, like a sidebar`"

But don't how to make appear my form appears like in that example? Please help, what should I do to make it able so in this   Bookmarklet  to call script.js so the form below to be showed like a sidebar or a popup? Please help!

EDIT:

I want to save those data `name` and `category` using an ajax request.
Here's a google spreadsheet where I want to save those data `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTlfje4H-K3KyvBvUDqIA0z7pz_VQpijJV5NcbwX1Rs/edit?usp=sharing`

when I do this nothing is done nly on submit button click concent inside iframe is replaced by main index.html . No error and no console log? I don't get it? I'm new on this.
My code:

```
(function(){
var f = '<form action="" method="post"> Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">Category <select name="category" id="category"><option value="first">First</option><option value="second">Second</option><option value="third">Third</option></select><br><input type="submit"></form>';
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(f);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

$("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var category = $('#category').val();
        console.log("po ajax" , name , category);
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTlfje4H-K3KyvBvUDqIA0z7pz_VQpijJV5NcbwX1Rs/edit?usp=sharing",
                data: { "name": name,"category": category},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                statusCode: {
                    0: function () {
                        // window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
                        console.log("error");
                    },
                    200: function () {
                        // window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
                        console.log("ok");
                    }
                }
            });
   });


})()
```

Here's the result: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
**document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(my_script);})()**
was missing from

```
<p><a href="javascript:(function(){my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');my_script.type='text/javascript';my_script.src='script.js?x=';"> Bookmarklet</a></p>
```

change it to

```
 <p><a href="javascript:(function(){my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');my_script.type='text/javascript';my_script.src='script.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(my_script);})();"> Bookmarklet</a></p>
```

It  place your on fly created js file inside head tag. You can place oit anywhere

2) Form should be created by js, you just can't place HTML in js file.
demo code example(script.js):

```
(function(){
var f = '<form action=" ">Name: <input type="text" name="name">Category <select name="category"><option value="volvo">First</option><option value="saab">Second</option><option value="fiat">Third</option></select><br><input type="submit"></form>';
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(f);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

})()
```

You can put css dynamically or open html file in iframe directly, many possibilites.
Question are welcome.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it really helped me. If you have time, I have two questions, first, why every time I click on bookmarklet button on bookmark bar another iframe is added , second I added an ajax post request when I click on it ajax is not executed but something weird is happened because the HTML page is inside ajax. please check my edit

Comment: Good to know , it help. I just give you the demo example only. You cannot bind event to element that is in iframe from current page.

Comment: How can I do that / :(

Comment: If I want to call here a html file what would be the difference? `<p><a href="javascript:(function(){my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');my_script.type='text/javascript';my_script.src='script.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(my_script);})();"> Bookmarklet</a></p>` Sorry if I'm taking your time

Comment: No, not a problem. Your example site have provided a good demo. You can call .html file in Iframe and that .html file should contain form tags and ajax post code.
From JS, First creat div and put iframe in it. Call you html file from that iframe. Write css to Float a div above page content.